# C# Validation attribute and decimals

Tags: c#, validation

I am writing a validation attribute:

```
public class MyAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object aValue)
    {

    }
}
```

but I am losing the least significant digits because the decimal is being passed as an object. So for instance:

```
(object)0.00
0    //I need 0.00
(object)1.00
1
(object)1.23
1.23
(object)1.230
1.23   //I need 1.230
```

As I am doing some validation based on the exact decimal value supplied namely 1.230 as distinct from 1.23 although mathematically the same, for my purposes they are different.

Is there any way to get the original decimal value when writing a validation attribute?

Comment: is there any reason you can't use generics? is object always a number?

Comment: How is generics going to help here? IsValid() always provides an object? I would be happy with a solution where the attribute can only be applied to decimal properties and hence always have say IsValid(decomal aValue) but I don't see how this is possible?

Comment: decimals are objects...

I guess what im trying to get at is that you can just call

        public bool IsValid(decimal value)
        {
            return base.IsValid((decimal)value);
        }
in your class

Comment: Perhaps if you could explain *why* `1.23 != 1.230` in your case we could better help you, because as far as decimals are concerned `1.23 == 1.230`.

Comment: @Muckeypuck Yes I could have IsValid(decimal aValue) but I am trying to use ValidationAttribute so that it can be used as annotations on properties as needed.

Comment: @CraigW. A closed system I don't have access to treats them differently (!) so I am exploring my options here so that we can at least know what came in to our system <i>exactly</i>

Comment: Note that the `decimal` type keeps some notion of the precision, however `double` does not. You can inspect the contents of the decimal using `decimal.GetBits`. If you compare the bits of 1.230m to 1.23m, you will see they are not the same. What is the exact type of the object being passed to IsValid?

Comment: @mikez It will be a decimal. IsValid() is from MS's ValudationAttributeClass https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationAttribute);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5.2);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true

Comment: If it is decimal then there should be no loss of precision when converting to object, unless you are going through some other kind of transformation before getting into IsValid. Your examples aren't even all that clear because those are not decimals. Those are doubles, so of course the precision is gone.

Comment: @mikez yep that was my bad. I should have used decimal representation. My unit tests had the same issue and hence the confusion. Muckeypuck proved that all is well in his solution and I now have the expected outcomes I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are passing in a decimal as an object it stays a decimal. Note how for demo two i cast it as a string and test the length after the decimal point.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            decimal demo1 = 1.2311M;
            decimal demo2 = 1.2300M;
            decimal demo3 = 1.00M;
            decimal demo4 = 1M;

            if (IsValid(demo1))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ValueKeptZero(demo1));
            }

            if (IsValid(demo2))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ValueKeptZero(demo2));
            }

            if (IsValid(demo3))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ValueKeptZero(demo3));
            }

            if (IsValid(demo4))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ValueKeptZero(demo4));
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static bool IsValid(object value)
        {

            if (!(value.GetType() == typeof(decimal)))
                return false;

            decimal tmp = (decimal)value;

            if(tmp == 1.23M)
            {
                string test = tmp.ToString();

                if(test.Substring(test.IndexOf(".") + 1).Length != 4)
                {
                    return false;
                }

            }

            return true;

        }

        static decimal ValueKeptZero(object value)
        {
            return (decimal)value;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: @all my unit tests were silently truncating the zeroes, but when I tweaked it to use x.xxM notation then all was well. I now have zeroes when I expect them.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way that you can do this type of validation based on a `decimal` being passed.  Decimal `1.23` is the same as `1.230` (end of story) and there is no way to determine a difference.

You need to change you validation to accept a `string`.

Comment: Can you show me an example of using a ValidationAttribute that passes a string? Also that would be the same issue I guess that the least significant digits will be lost in the conversion to the string anyway?